# Asynchronous Post within a class

Tags: objective-c

I have a LocationServices class that has two functions getLocation and postCordinates. In postCordinates im calling an asynchronous post with a completion handler. In the
view controller i call a instance of the class and call postCordinates. When I call the function  [location postCordinates:completion:^(NSString *response) { I get the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'completion'

LocationServices.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface LocationServices : NSObject<CLLocationManagerDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
 CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

- (MKCoordinateRegion*)getLocation;
- (void)postCordinates:completion:(void (^)(NSString *response))completion;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *serverResponse;

@end
```

LocationServices.m

```
- (void) postCordinates: completion:(void (^)(NSString *response))completion{


    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary
                              dictionaryWithObjects:@[latitude,longitude]
                              forKeys:@[@"latitude",@"longitude"]];

    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:postURL]
                                                           cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval: 60.0];
    // Http Method

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];


    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                         if (!error && data){ // here you can check also response.statusCode if needed

                                             serverResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

                                             NSString *response = [serverResponse objectForKey:@"Response"];

                                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                                 completion(response);


                                             });
                                         }else {
                                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                 completion(nil);
                                             });
                                         }
                                     }] resume];

}
```

View Controller that creates instance of class

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex {

//Get the name of the current pressed button
NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

 [location postCordinates:completion:^(NSString *response) {

if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Everyone"]) {

    [location 
     if ([response isEqualToString:@"200"]){

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@""
                                  message:@"Username or Password is incorrect"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alert show];

        }
        else{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@""
                                  message:@"Username or Password is incorrect"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alert show];
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", response);

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)postCordinates:completion:(void (^)(NSString *response))completion;
```

is syntactically incorrect as

```
[location postCordinates:completion:^(NSString *response) {
```

is. Probably you want to have

```
- (void)postCordinatesCompletion:(void (^)(NSString *response))completion;
```

Comment: Did you change all three locations?